# java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid certificates

Tags: java

Взял лаунчер из этого репозитория: [Launcher Minecraft](https://github.com/new-sashok724/Launcher/)

Пытаюсь запустить его и получаю исключение.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid certificates
at launcher.helper.SecurityHelper.verifyCertificates(SecurityHelper.java:376)
at launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:243)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

SecurityHelper.java:376

```
@LauncherAPI
public static void verifyCertificates(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (!isValidCertificates(clazz)) {
        throw new SecurityException("Invalid certificates");
    }
}
```

Launcher.java:243

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Throwable {
    JVMHelper.verifySystemProperties(Launcher.class);
    SecurityHelper.verifyCertificates(Launcher.class);
    LogHelper.printVersion("Launcher");

    // Start Launcher
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    try {
        new Launcher().start(args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogHelper.error(e);
        return;
    }
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    LogHelper.debug("Launcher started in %dms", Duration.between(start, end).toMillis());
}
```

Подписываю jar таким путем.

```
jarsigner -keystore "C:\Launcher\.keystore" -storepass "mypass" -sigfile LAUNCHER "C:\Launcher\Launcher.jar" "myalias"
```

Здесь проверяется на сертификацию.

```
@LauncherAPI
public static boolean isValidCertificates(Class<?> clazz) {
    // Verify META-INF/MANIFEST.MF certificate
    Resource metaInf = JVMHelper.UCP.getResource(JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
    if (metaInf == null || !isValidCertificates(metaInf.getCertificates())) {
        return false;
    }

    // Verify class certificate
    CodeSource source = clazz.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
    return source != null && isValidCertificates(source.getCertificates());
}
```

**UPD**:

Оказывается LAUNCHER.DSA и LAUNCHER.SF не записываются в jar. Хоть я и подписываю jar при билде.

[image: Скриншот поиска сертификатов]

Если просто сделать билд без запуска и изучить Launcher.jar, то видно, что LAUNCHER.DSA и LAUNCHER.SF присутствуют. 
Возникает вопрос: почему при сборке LAUNCHER.DSA и LAUNCHER.SF не попадают в Launcher.jar?

[image: Скриншот внутренностей Launcher.jar]

Comment: нужно понять к какому хоту обращается и добавить сертификат в систему

Comment: LWGL  совпадает с версией клиента?

Comment: Ты наверное говоришь "к какому хосту"? Как добавить сертификат в систему? Где проверить версии клиента на LWGL?

Comment: про версию клиента не могу сказать. Да, "к какому хосту". попробуйте пробебажиться и посмотреть что и как работает метод isValidCertificate(Class)

Comment: Продебажил. Дописал в конце вопроса. При сборке ключи не кладутся в jar.

Comment: -storepass "mypass" разве в ковычках указывается? каков результат выполнения подписи ?

Comment: Результат подписи: jar signed.
И jar, который лежит в папке подписан. Может происходит подпись, а потом новая сборка зачищает jar? Может где-то косячу со сборкой.

Comment: видимо так и есть. проконтролируйте каждый шаг и посмотрите изменения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55268/discussion-between-makaron-iv-and-senior-pomidor).